# prove that any self complementary graph is connected

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I have already shown that if a graph G=(V,E) is self complementary then we must have |V|=4k or |V|=4k+1 for some positive integer k, but now I am struggling to find a way to show that every self complementary graph is connected. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What does self-complementary mean?

Comment: When a graph G is self-complementary, then that means that G is isomorphic to it's Complement. However, here we are not talking about the graph of a function, but rather a graph made up of a vertex set and an edge set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that question?

Comment: I wasn't certain whether the graph just had to be isomorphic to its complement, or whether there was some kind of additional restriction. It's a term I've never heard before, so I thought it a good idea to ask.

Comment: That's fair, I respect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a famous observation of Erdös that a graph or its compliment must be connected. Confirm this and use this for your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will use that